# Criterion for a equalizer to be a homotopy equalizer in spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f,g\colon X\rightarrow Y$ be maps between spaces.

I am looking for criteria for the equalizer of $f$ and $g$ to be a homotopy equalizer and  I am happy to get answers for whatever model category of spaces you prefer.

As the equalizer of $f$ and $g$ can be written as the pullback of $(f,g)\colon X\rightarrow Y\times Y$ along the diagonal $Y\rightarrow Y\times Y$, it is a homotopy equalizer if $(f,g)$ is a fibration, which unfortunately doesn't happen very often.

I feel there should be something weaker which is more likely to happen. An indication for this is the following thought. If $k\colon Z\rightarrow Y$ and $l\colon W\rightarrow Y$, the pullback of $k$ and $l$ is the equalizer of the maps from $Z\times W$ to $Y$ given by projecting to one factor first and then using $k$ respectively $l$. The map analogous to $(f,g)$ is then $k\times l$. But $k\times l$ is often not a fibration even if the pullback is a homotopy pullback, e.g. if only one of the maps is a fibration and the other is not.

Comment: Write the homotopy equalizer $hE(f,g)$ as the homotopy pullback of 

$X\xrightarrow{\Delta} X\times X\xleftarrow{(p,q)} N(f,g)$

Where $N(f,g)$ is the homotopy pullback of $f$ and $g$ and $(p,q):N(f,g)\rightarrow X\times X$ are the canonical maps. When $f$ or $g$ is a fibration then $N(f,g)$ is homotopy equivalent to the strict pull back $P(f,g)$ of the two maps. When both $f$ and $g$ are fibrations, then the map $(p,q):N(f,g)\rightarrow X\times X$ is a fibration so therefore $hE(f,g)$ is homotopy equivalent to the strict pullback of the above and this is precisely the equalizer $E(f,g)$.

Comment: This is an answer.

Comment: @Tyrone Why is the map $(p,q): N(f,g) \rightarrow X \times X$ a fibration? Take $X = Y$ and $f,g$ to be identity then the $(p,q)$ is just the diagonal map which is not a fibration.

Comment: $N(f,g)$ is the homotopy pullback, not strict pullback.

Comment: I still don't understand; Assume model category is right proper, then if either of $f$ or $g$ is a fibration then homotopy pullback is same (weakly equivalent) as strict pullback

Comment: I'm afraid you're asking about something that I left as a comment, almost two years ago. Right now I barely have time to reread the question, let alone think about what I wrote. I seem to remember my comment was inspired by May and Ponto's Book "More Concise...", so I'd suggest reading their section on homotopy equalisers if you want more details.

Comment: Since @Tyrone didn't have time to fix the comment five years ago, let me be more assertive and help others avoid going down the fruitless rabbit hole I just got back out of: the first comment is wrong. The issue is that $N(f,g) \to X \times X$ is very rarely a fibration. The case $f=g=\mathrm{id}$ is indeed a counterexample.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi it is proved on page 98 of Spanier's book (Co. 3) that $N(id_Y,id_Y)=Y^I\rightarrow Y\times Y$ is a fibration. $N(f,g)\rightarrow X\times X$ is the pullback of this by $f\times g:X\times X\rightarrow Y\times Y$, and hence also a fibration (this needs no properties of $f,g$). The issue is the assertion that  'the strict pullback of the above and this is precisely the equalizer', which is clearly false: this pullback is the homotopy equaliser. I apologise for any rabbit holes.

Comment: @Tyrone I see. Because I had read your conclusion, I thought you meant we could take whatever representative of the homotopy pullback, but it seems you meant to always take one specific model ($\{ (x,y,h) \mid h(0) = x, h(1) = y \}$). Either way, the result is false.

Answer (score 1):

It is not sufficient that $f$ and $g$ are both fibrations.

Here is a counterexample in the category $\mathbf{Cat}$. The counterexample works both in the Thomason model structure (which gives a model category of spaces) as well as the canonical model structure.

Let $I$ be the "walking isomorphism": the category with two objects that is equivalent to $1$.

Let $F$ and $G$ be the two automorphisms of $I$. These are isomorphisms, and thus (acyclic) fibrations.

Since $I$ is contractible, every homotopy equalizer of $F$ and $G$ is also a contractible category.

The strict equalizer of $F$ and $G$ is the empty category.